# How to build X in (a point-buy system)

Tags: discussion, on-topic

In strictly point-buy systems (like GURPS and HERO System) you can build pretty much any character/vehicle/gadget you can think of if you know how to combine the powers and modifications thereof. Trouble comes of not knowing how to combine them appropriately.

I'm wondering if those sorts of questions would be okay here. (I suppose they'd be along the lines of [optimization](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) questions.)

For example:

- How to build the Silver Surfer's surfboard in HERO System
- How to point build a taser in GURPS
- What would mimic the *Holy Avenger* from D&D in Fantasy HERO?

I suppose there's a risk that this could get into "design my character for me" territory. (*"Build me Batman!"*) but within reason that might not be so bad ("How to build Batman on 250 points").

Would these sorts of questions be on-topic here? If not, why not?

Comment: Can you make this more clear as to why these *aren't* optimisation questions and bound to the same rules?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton The goal of an optimization question is how to best accomplish an in-game effect. The goal of questions is how to best emulate an out-of-game (or, as with the Avenger, an outside-this-game) element using game tools.

Comment: I'm still hazy on why the same rules don't apply. It's the pattern "How do I accomplish [goal] in [system x]" I don't see the in/out game difference... anywhere?

Comment: I want to build gandalf == I want to build an awesome wizard who saves the day with plot powers.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton The difference between the two is that you've established what "building Gandalf" means to you in a way that's useful. Take the example of "build me Batman on 250 points." Well, Batman as a character has been around for 75 years; you'll have to narrow down what parts of the character feel inescapably Batmann-y to you. Moreover, your Batman will almost certainly differ from my Batman.

Answer (score 8):

### These are classes of poorly specified optimisation questions which should be closed until they can fit our requirements.

Jadasc said, in a comment:

> The difference between the two is that you've established what "building Gandalf" means to you in a way that's useful. Take the example of "build me Batman on 250 points." Well, Batman as a character has been around for 75 years; you'll have to narrow down what parts of the character feel inescapably Batmann-y to you. Moreover, your Batman will almost certainly differ from my Batman. –

Therefore, questions of this ilk cannot rely on a shared cultural touchstone to provide requirements, therefore questions of this ilk are "unclear what you're asking."

Therefore, by operationalising the ideas of the trope or ideal into the game world, it does become possible to have a best answer, and follow our other optimisation rules. Answers, however, will likely have a hard time with that first step, as there are too many unstated assumptions campaign by campaign.

Comment: Not that *some* such questions are good fits for the site, but these are, as you have noted, just optimization questions;  "How do I build a tazer in X" is probably fine.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are some pitfalls here to watch out for. The first is that in a point-based system, there's often no one "best" way to build a given thing, which means they might be prone to list answers. The other is that without careful structuring, deciding which elements of a thing are crucial to include or to exclude can be pretty opinion based, which could take these questions into the "so what level is Gandalf/clan is Lestat" territory.

Comment: [Relevant!](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23095/4398)

Comment: @BESW Can you give me a reason not to historical lock that answer?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton The answer in particular or the whole question?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Not really, no. A question with more specific criteria might pass muster, but this one's Too Broad/Not Clear What You're Asking. Historical lock (as it's a super-common question which got great answers) seems appropriate.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton It was very nearly closed before, until my answer "redeemed" it. I'm not sure that's really a reason for it to be open though by our current standards, especially since one good challenge-frame answer doesn't prevent more listy-answers in the future.

Comment: I second the motion to historical lock that down